# How to implement Groupping in Nativescript Vue RadDataForm?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Want to use Fields grouping Documention is not prvided event the topic of grouping nor the example. Most of the example are using typescript. Event the Google is not showing the result.

```
      <RadDataForm
        ref="dataform"
        :source="customerForm"
        :metadata="customerFormMetadata"
        :groups="groups"
      />

customerFormMetadata: {
        isReadOnly: false,
        commitMode: "Immediate",
        validationMode: "Immediate",
        propertyAnnotations: [
          {
            name: "customer_name_1",
            displayName: "Customer Name",
            index: 0,
            groupName: "Personal",
            editor: "Text"
          },

groups: [
        Object.assign(new PropertyGroup(), {
          name: "Personal",
          collapsible: true,
          collapsed: false
        }),

        Object.assign(new PropertyGroup(), {
          name: "Address",
          collapsible: true,
          collapsed: true
        })
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping doesn't require any addtional configuration while using with Vue, it's pretty straight forward as described in the core [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/DataForm/Groups/dataform-groups-overview).

**Example**

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <RadDataForm :source="person" :metadata="groupMetaData" />
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
    import RadDataForm from "nativescript-ui-dataform/vue";
    Vue.use(RadDataForm);

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                person: {
                    name: "John",
                    age: 23,
                    email: "john@company.com",
                    city: "New York",
                    street: "5th Avenue",
                    streetNumber: 11
                },
                groupMetaData: {
                    propertyAnnotations: [{
                            name: "city",
                            index: 3,
                            groupName: "Address",
                            editor: "Picker",
                            valuesProvider: [
                                "New York",
                                "Washington",
                                "Los Angeles"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "street",
                            index: 4,
                            groupName: "Address"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "streetNumber",
                            index: 5,
                            editor: "Number",
                            groupName: "Address"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "age",
                            index: 1,
                            editor: "Number",
                            groupName: "Main Info"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "email",
                            index: 2,
                            editor: "Email",
                            groupName: "Main Info"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "name",
                            index: 0,
                            groupName: "Main Info"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

**Edit:**

As discussed in the docs, to make the Group collapsible use the `groupUpdate` event.

```
onGroupUpdate: function(args) {
    let nativeGroup = args.group;
    if (args.ios) {
         nativeGroup.collapsible = true;
    } else {
         nativeGroup.setExpandable(true);
    }
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?id=XLKFoC&template=play-vue&v=6)

Comment: I put it wrong group was created but not collapsable how do make it collapsable. Here is the code https://play.nativescript.org/?id=XLKFoC&template=play-vue&v=5